# AppCenter: Upload Certificate files for iOS build config using API

Tags: c#, .net

The App Center claims that it can do all the builds and deployment steps with API. Certificate files need to be uploaded to configure iOS build settings. (.p12 and .mobileprovision) There is a [link](https://intercom.help/appcenter/en/articles/1750391-build-api-how-to-upload-a-provisioning-profile-and-or-distribution-certificate-to-app-center-and-configure-a-branch-for-build-via-the-api) that describe this. But it not contains example and I think I have a problem with upload my files. Here is my code for upload file to appcenter:

```
        private async Task<string> AppCenterUpload(string filePath, string orgName, string appName)
    {
        var createAssetReq = new RestRequest($"/v0.1/apps/{orgName}/{appName}/file_asset");
        createAssetReq.AddHeader("X-API-TOKEN", apiKey);
        var createAssetRes = await appCenterClient.PostAsync<dynamic>(createAssetReq);
        string assetId = createAssetRes["id"];
        string uploadDomain = createAssetRes["uploadDomain"];
        string urlEncodedToken = createAssetRes["urlEncodedToken"];

        double fileSize = new FileInfo(filePath.ToString()).Length;

        var fileName = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        var uploadProcessReq = new RestRequest($"{uploadDomain}/upload/set_metadata/{assetId}?file_name={fileName}&file_size={fileSize}&token={urlEncodedToken}");
        uploadProcessReq.AddHeader("X-API-TOKEN", apiKey);
        var uploadProcessRes = await appCenterClient.PostAsync<dynamic>(uploadProcessReq);
        JsonArray chunkList = uploadProcessRes["chunk_list"];
        long chunkSize = uploadProcessRes["chunk_size"];
        string id = uploadProcessRes["id"];
        
        var item = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        int startIndex = 0;
        for(int i =0; i< chunkList.Count(); i++)
        {
            int chunkLength = chunkSize > item.Count() ? item.Count() : (int)chunkSize;
            byte[] buffers = new byte[chunkLength];
            Array.Copy(item, startIndex, buffers, 0, chunkLength);
            startIndex = chunkLength;
            var startUploadReq = new RestRequest($"{uploadDomain}/upload/upload_chunk/{id}?block_number={chunkList[i]}&token={urlEncodedToken}");
            startUploadReq.AddJsonBody(buffers);
            await appCenterClient.PostAsync<dynamic>(startUploadReq);
        }

        var latestReq = new RestRequest($"{uploadDomain}/upload/finished/{id}?token={urlEncodedToken}");
        latestReq.AddHeader("X-API-TOKEN", apiKey);
        var resx = await appCenterClient.PostAsync<dynamic>(latestReq);
        bool result = resx["error"];

        if (result) return null;
        return id;
    }
```

I think I have a problem with upload bytes chunks in pass them as request's body. Do you have any idea for resolve this? Or maybe I'm in mistake.